# Is there any specific ayah in the Coran to oblige the wearing of hijab?

Tags: quran, hijab, fard

Is there any verse in the Coran that shows that Hijab is obligatory?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0QvPAo_JB4                                 short clip about the commandment of the hijab in the holy Qur'an.

Answer (score 4):

### Qur'an

There are these two ayah:

> **And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment** except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might succeed. -- [Qur'an 24:31](http://quran.com/24:31)
>
> **O Prophet, tell your wives and your daughters and the women of the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer garments.** That is more suitable that they will be known and not be abused. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful. -- [Qur'an 33:59](https://quran.com/33:59)

See Islam Awakened for further translations of [Qur'an 24:31](http://islamawakened.com/quran/24/31/) and [Qur'an 33:59](http://islamawakened.com/quran/33/59/).

Also relevant is [Qur'an 24:60](http://quran.com/24:60): "...women of post-menstrual age who have no desire for marriage - there is no blame upon them for putting aside their outer garments [but] not displaying adornment...".

### Ahadith

The most relevant ahadith I'm aware of are:

> (the wife of the Prophet) 'Umar bin Al-Khattab used to say to Allah's Messenger "Let your wives be veiled" But he did not do so. The wives of the Prophet used to go out to answer the call of nature at night only at Al-Manasi.' Once Sauda, the daughter of Zam'a went out and she was a tall woman. 'Umar bin Al-Khattab saw her while he was in a gathering, and said, "I have recognized you, O Sauda!" He ('Umar) said so as he was anxious for some Divine orders regarding the veil (the veiling of women.) So Allah revealed the Verse of veiling. -- Narrated 'Aisha ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/14))

This gives some background as to the motivation behind observing veil.

> May Allah bestow His Mercy on the early emigrant women. When Allah revealed: "... and to draw their veils all over their Juyubihinna (i.e., their bodies, faces, necks and bosoms)..." (V.24:31) they tore their Murat (woolen dresses or waist-binding clothes or aprons etc.) and covered their heads and faces with those torn Muruts. -- Narrated 'Aishah ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4758))

This hadith indicates how important it is considered to observe.  (Other ahadith are listed on [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/13998).)

### Is hijab considered fard?

As you might expect (given the diversity of hijab seen in the Muslim world), there is diversity of opinion of what constitutes hijab.  As to whether or not hijab is [fard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fard) (obligatory), I'm yet to see a scholar disagree that it's fard:

> The first commandment applies to women when they go out.  Then they are to use an outer garment which should cover their whole body.  -- Malik Ghulam Farid (ed), The Holy Qur'an, Arabic Text with English Translation & Short Commentary, 2003 ([pdf](http://www.alislam.org/quran/Holy-Quran-English.pdf), within the discussion on pages 717-719; the author even includes covering the face as part of the commandment)
>
> Hijab is obligatory for all Muslim women who have reached the age of puberty. -- Islam Q&A [47569](https://islamqa.info/en/47569) (and also [6991](https://islamqa.info/en/6991), [13998](https://islamqa.info/en/13998), [20475](https://islamqa.info/en/20475))
>
> Almighty Allah ordered the women to let the two ends of their headgear extend onto their bosoms so that they conceal their ears, the neck, and the upper part of the bosom also. -- [Al Islam](https://www.al-islam.org/hijab-muslim-womens-dress-islamic-or-cultural-sayyid-muhammad-rizvi/quran-and-hijab#2-then-what-does-clause-%E2%80%9Cplacing-khumur-over-bosoms%E2%80%9D-mean), which cites Ar-Razi, [at-Tafsiru 'l-Kabir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir_al-Kabir_(al-Razi)), vol. 23, p. 179
>
> This is a command from Allah to the believing women, and jealousy on His part over the wives of His believing servants. It is also to distinguish the believing women from the women of the Jahiliyyah and the deeds of the pagan women. -- [QTafsir.com](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2430&Itemid=79)
>
> Sheikh [Yusuf Al Qaradawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yusuf_al-Qaradawi)... also states that all of the scholars throughout history from various groups such as the Sufis, the Dhahiris (the Literalists), the fuqahaa’ (jurists), and the scholars of hadith unanimously agree that it is fard for the believing woman to cover her hair. -- [Virtual Mosque](http://www.virtualmosque.com/ummah/women/hijab-niqab/hijab-fard-obligation-or-fiction/)

And I personally observe hijab because of (a) what it says in the Qur'an, and (b) I'm unaware of any reasonable dissenting opinion.

See also: [How can we be so sure that women must wear hijab when the Qur`an does not prescribe it in clear words?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25945/17163)

Comment: Thank you for your answer , so if I have well understood , the recommendation of wearing Hijab has first been made by Omar ibn al khattab , Right ?

Comment: I'm not well-informed about it's history.  I hear it's also mentioned in the Bible ([1 Corinthians 11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+11:2-16)), and even Mary was known to wear a headscarf (see [this Christianity.SE question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/36952/9617)).  It's plausible, therefore, that the recommendation was in the Gospel and predates Muhammad and the Qur'an.  I don't know for sure.

Comment: @hananesenhadji 'Omar ibn al-Khattab has first thought of it, the revelation confirmed the order of covering soon afterwards, at least according to that hadith.

Comment: As rightly stated in your answer, the Christians also observed hijab. The reason why in the Qur'an women are not ask to cover the hair is the fact that at the time of revelation it was already a custom for women to cover their hair, but they did not cover their chest. It was worn in a way that the women would cover the hair and tie it in the neck.  Therefore, Allah swt. asked them to put the hair cover over their chest.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** @noor Comments are intended for *constructive criticism*, not for argument and debate of controversial points. From http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/275/22: "For the purpose of this site, assume that each sect's hadith are valid, and that each sect's accepted imams are reliable."

Comment: Also, adding up a bit, in some cases Umar (RA) suggested something and an ayah in accordance with that got released, for example, Umar (RA) was the first one that suggested that alcohol should be prohibited in Islam and quickly enough, Jibreel (AS) came with the revelation of making it prohibited, and according to many scholars there are countless ayahs like this that just came down because Umar (RA) suggested them, he was a significant personality in Islam.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special verse in the Qur'an that obliges the observance of hijab?
Verse of Hijab (Noor: 31) speaks of the necessity of women wearing hijab. This verse is one of the Quranic reasons of the jurists for the necessity of hijab.
Other verses are also known as the verse of hijab. Among them is verse 59 of Surah Al-Ahzab, which is called the verse of Jalbab.

Ref: https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D9%87_%D8%AD%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%A8